# PHP script posting to db not working

Tags: php

I'm sure this is pretty elementary but I'm new to php.  Can someone tell me why this code won't write to the table?  I just simply want the form to update a table in the db.  Everthing works except the data in the table is not being overwritten.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

```
<?php
$username="username";
$password="password";
$dbname="database";
$usertable="table";
$connect = @mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)or die
("cannot connect to db");
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$show=$_POST['show'];
$pro=$_POST['pro'];
$twmo=$_POST['twmo'];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO $usertable VALUES
('$show','pro','$twmo')" );

mysql_close($connect);
header("Location: http://www.myhomepage.com");

?>
```

Comment: I'd start my removing the `@` prefix from your connection function, so you can see any warnings it might be throwing. Also, as an aside, you should be untainting your `$_POST` variables - at the moment you have a SQL injection vulnerability. Lastly if your table name is really "table" then that probably needs quoting, or better still renaming, since it is a SQL reserved word.

Comment: You'll want to use the mysqli functions or PDO functions instead of the mysql functions. mysql functions have been deprecated.

Comment: It's a good idea to do `INSERT` operations with column name specifications, btw, so your code will still work if you re-order your columns.

Comment: Your data will not be overwritten with an INSERT statement - INSERT is used to insert a new row into the table. Specifiy columns names as well - eg INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

- **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.**
  A malicious user could easily wipe out your entire table.
- **You shouldn't even be using `mysql_*`!**
  It's deprecated and bad style! Go find a tutorial for `mysqli` or PDO, don't relay on articles from 2008.

**Regarding the actual question**, try some debugging yourself. You're not checking if any of your queries succeed. When you perform a query, `mysql_query()` returns either a resource or `FALSE` on failure. Check if this is happening, so you can find out where exactly the error is happening and what it is using `mysql_error()`.

If your table is actually called `table`, then that's the problem. `table` is a reserved keyword. You could fix it by encapsulating it with ticks `, but really you should just change its name. It isn't useful at all to have a table named table. Call it what it contains.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and heads up for mysqli.  I'll start searching for the tutorials.  Just as an fyi, all of the $fields are renamed for the post.